# auto completing a windows security popup form on a website

Tags: vb.net

I have built a web application that collects data. After the data capture completes, users can obtain a PDF report with the information they entered. To provide the report, I used SQL server's report server to serve the report. When a request is made for the report, the server gives a windows security dialog box to see if the request is allowed to be served by the report server. How do I programmatically complete this form and get the report? I'm trying to prevent users from having to login.

I was thinking: What if I created an html form that pointed at the report like my original request and contained the same fields as the windows security box? Couldn't then I fill the form with that single username and password that I gave to all the users so that the form is submitted, validated and the report returned without having to enter the username and password?

Part of me thinks that this would not work as the form validation is a separate process from the rendering of HTML.

Comment: At a guess, can you add the application pool identity used by the website to the allowed users for the report server? [Grant user access to a report server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/grant-user-access-to-a-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the article. I'm not sure its what I need. I have the server configured with a user that is allowed to retrieve the reports via a web request. I've given the credentials of that user to everyone who will be accessing the report. This part works. I'm simply trying to set things up so users do not have to login when requesting the report. I want them to be automatically logged in. BTW, the server is 2008 R2 Native Mode.